# How to linearize a constraint that containing square of sum of product?

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations, linearization

I am working on an optimization problem. In order to solve it using CPLEX, we need to linearize the non-linear constraint stated in the following.

$$\left(\sum_{i,j \in A}\mu _{i,j}X_{i,j,t}\right) ^2 \ge \sum_{i,j \in A}\sigma_{i,j}^2X_{i,j,t}$$

Where $X_{i,j,t}$ is binary variable and all remain ones are parameters.

Comment: What did you try? How large is $A$?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to expand the square and linearize each resulting product of binary variables in [the usual way](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).

Alternatively, just use the MIQCP solver in CPLEX.